# How to properly segment algorithms within a Python file

Tags: python

I am submitting an assignment and I have to include more than one algorithm within the **same** python file.

My current idea is to do the following:

```
# ----------------------------Algorithm 1---------------------------#

# Algorithm 1 Functions

# ----------------------------Algorithm 2---------------------------#

# Algorithm 2 Functions

if __name__ == "__main__":
    alg = input("0 for Algorithm 1 / 1 forAlgorithm 2: ")
```

If there a standard/more proper way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: Can you split it up onto two files, one for each algo (and maybe a third for the `main` part)?

Comment: Python has style guide like PEP8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Sadly no, everything must be within the same file

Comment: You could encapsulate the algorithms into two classes, each with the methods (and possibly state) relevant to that algorithm. Also allows you to make specialized versions of algorithms using inheritance. Or if classes are not an option, you could create helper functions within the algorithms "main entry" function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following is a bit too simplistic:

```
# ----------------------------Algorithm 1---------------------------#

def main1():
    # Algorithm 1 Functions
    print('Algorithm 1 Functions')

# ----------------------------Algorithm 2---------------------------#
def main2():
    # Algorithm 2 Functions
    print('Algorithm 2 Functions')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    alg = input("0 for Algorithm 1 / 1 forAlgorithm 2: ")
    if alg == 0: 
        main1()
    elif alg == 1: 
        main2()
    else:
        print('Incorrect input')
```

Comment: How is this different from OP's own approach?

Comment: OP only has an input statement and is not doing anything with it. Question is not clear if he needs help with finalizing what he has, or that he needs a complete new approach. In case of a new approach more info is needed on "how to select" the said algorithms, what type of input this has, and if there is something in the data which can be used to select which code to run. If that is the case you can do classes or consider other approaches.